# How to prevent the entire Next.js app from crashing if there is a client-side error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am using URL Inspection -> Mobile Usability tool provided by Google Search Console to inspect why some of the pages are not being indexed.

This is the URL I am testing:

https://ray.run/blog/playwright-mobile-app-testing-for-android-a-comprehensive-guide

As I am doing this, I discovered that Google Search Console is not able to load these pages. What's worse, the entire page is replaced with black screen saying there is a client error.

Aside from figuring out why it is failing, given that the page has been already rendered server side, how do I not replace the page content with an error?

[image]